# Is 'log' (short for 'logarithm') considered too informal for an academic paper in the social sciences?

Tags: formality

Should I write (in the main body of the text)

> The dependent variable is the logarithm of GDP.

or

> The dependent variable is the log of GDP.

or even:

> The dependent variable is log GDP.

It strikes me that I rarely see 'logarithm' fully spelt out, even in the main body of the text of academic papers. (More context: I am writing an economics paper.)

Comment: Well, for any social science, statistics is absolutely necessary knowledge, so you can probly say "log" confidently; but you should also be specific about exactly what transformations you've performed on the data, giving precise equations whenever necessary. To start with, for instance, do you mean ln (GDP) or log₁₀ (GDP)? And what units is GDP represented in, and what's your source for the data? Etc.

Comment: are you taking the natural log, in which case use 'ln'

Comment: I think it would be best to better specify the nature of the dependent variable. If it is "the logarithm of GDP", specify the base of the logarithm (base 2? base *e*? base 10?).

Comment: I think in economics it is conventional to assume that if not specified, 'log' or 'logarithm' refers to base *e*.

Answer (score 1):

Use the full spelling initially, while introducing the abbreviation. Then you can abbreviate from then on. Such as,

"The dependent variable is the logarithm, *or log*, of GDP."

Then throughout the rest of the paper you can use, *"The log of GDP..."*

Comment: I think the best, most formal way, which doesn't sound like you're having a conversaion in math class, would be to have a definition stating `lGDP = log(GDP)`, and then just use `lGDP` for the rest of the paper.